# SQL performance analysis

Tags: sql

I have a table 1 lac row with 50 columns. I know I have to select exactly one row and one column based on primary key. So what query I have to use either

```
SELECT * FROM <TAB_NAME> WHERE <IND_COL_NAME> = XXXXXX
```

or

```
SELECT COL_NAME FROM <TAB_NAME> WHERE <IND_COL_NAME> = XXXXXX
```

So any one tell me please which approach is better and why. from performance point of view. suppose this query is running frequently in an scalable application. Please specify the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal approach would be

```
 SELECT yourcolumn FROM yourtable WHERE yourcondition
```

It will generate less network traffic, and is a more precise statement of your requirements.

Additionally, if your table has columns of certain types, it avoids expensive querying of them, thus giving you improved performance

Comment: But why I can raise question * is better from dependency point of view. and other thing I have pointed the performance too. 'll this approach be faster than another one

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your indexes, however, in most cases that I can think of, the narrow select (`SELECT COL_NAME`) will perform better, as it gives SQL more 'options' on how to get to the data.

In general, for any given query, the best case scenario is to have an index which allows an index seek on your `WHERE` condition, but also includes the columns you need in your `SELECT`. This way, the RDBMS only needs to use the index to obtain the result of your query - it doesn't need the underlying table at all.

In MS SQL Server, a covering index will allow you to do exactly this.

It is unlikely that

```
SELECT * FROM <TAB_NAME> WHERE <IND_COL_NAME> = XXXXXX
```

will be optimal in many cases, since unless you have an index for `IND_COL_NAME` which includes all columns in the table (which would be wasteful storage wise, unless `<IND_COL_NAME>` is your clustered index). Otherwise, it means that the query would need to seek on an index for `<IND_COL_NAME>` and then join back into the physical table to retrieve the rest of the column data.

So for your narrow query

```
SELECT COL_NAME FROM <TAB_NAME> WHERE <IND_COL_NAME> = XXXXXX
```

the optimal index would be on `<IND_COL_NAME>`, which includes `COL_NAME`. Since you say that `<IND_COL_NAME>` is your primary key, it will be highly selective.

Comment: Please take a look on latest Comment

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `*` to specify the fields, always specify exactly the fields that you want.

When fetching a single row the data size difference is small, but you should generally get only what you need to reduce the bandwidth usage. Another aspect is that using `*` adds a dependency on the table design. If you later on add more fields to the table, the query would also fetch those fields, and that could mean that you get more data than fits in the buffer, and you get an exception.

When you get a single field (or a few fields) from the table there is a specific performance advantage. If you have an index for the key with the wanted field(s) as included columns, then the query can be run from the index only, not even touching the table itself.

Comment: As I know that (Oracle) stores data in DATA file. that is further segmented as DB_BLOCK and OS_BLOCK. As I have stated there is index so there will exact row location. Then after reaching at the DESIRED row they have to scan all the COLUMN (in worst case). then where the performance. between both of them other some more chunks of DATA in *  case.

Comment: @PavanSharma: Oracle doesn't have included columns in indexes, so you would make an index with the key and the wanted field. If you have that, all the needed information is in the index, and it doesn't have to read from the data file at all.

Comment: In Oracle ROW Data are stored in [{COL_SIZE,COL_VALUE},{COL_SIZE,COL_VALUE},{COL_SIZE,COL_VALUE}{COL_SIZE,COL_VALUE}...] fine. and Index is associated with a table, containing indexed Key Value with ROWID ( ROWID is a physical location of ROW where it stored in Data file). when ever we selecting data using indexed column it directly on the desired Physical Location (ROWID) then I think filter the record, for column. then How NARROW statement increase performance ?

Comment: @PavanSharma: If the index has both the key and the selected field, then it doesn't even have to use the ROWID to get the row, as all the data that is needed is in the index itself.